# How to show div based on dropdown selection in mvc4

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap, asp.net-mvc-4

My jQuery code is not working.

My View

```
<div class="col-sm-4">
    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.POVisit, new { @class = "control-  label",id="POVisit" })
        @Html.DropDownList("POVisitID", "Select")
    </div>
</div>

<div id ="OrderReceivedYesNo">
    <div class="col-sm-4">
        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.OrderReceived, new { @class = "control-label" })
            @Html.RadioButton("OrderReceived", 1) Yes
            @Html.RadioButton("OrderReceived", 0) No
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

My jquery code

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#OrderReceivedYesNo").hide();
});

$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#POVisit").on('change', function () {
        if (this.value == "Order") {
            $("#OrderReceivedYesNo").show();
        }
    });
});
```

The above code is not working. The POVisit Dropdown have 7 values which is directly fetch from Database. Initially i hide the **OrderReceived** radio buttons. If I select the "Order" value in `POVisit` DropDown it needs to show the **"OrderReceivedYesNo"** div. But the above code that show code is not working.

Comment: On question at a time!

Comment: You do not have an element with `id="POVisit"` so `$("#POVisit")` is undefined. You do however have dropdownlist with `id="POVisitID"` so change the script to `$("#POVisitID").change(function () {...`

Comment: <div id ="POVisit">
               <div class="col-sm-4">
                <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.POVisit, new { @class =     "control-label",id="POVisit" })
            @Html.DropDownList("POVisitID", "Select")
              </div>
                </div>
             </div>  now i change my code to this . still its not working

Comment: Do it as per my comment. Your just adding `id="POVisit"` to a `<div>` which does not have a change event! And remove `new { id="POVisit" }` from the `LabelFor()` as well.

Comment: ok let i have a check

Comment: I did same as like as per you said still its not working..

Comment: Of course it does - you have obviously still made a mistake. Put a console.log('xxx'); statement in the `$("#POVisitID").change(function () {` script and check the output.

Comment: wait i will show my code

Comment: And I have edited you question to delete the second one. Ask a new question for it.

Comment: <div class="col-sm-4">
                <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.POVisit, new { @class = "control-label"})
            @Html.DropDownList("POVisitID", "Select")
              </div>
                </div>                                                                                                       $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#POVisitID").change(function () {
            

            if (this.value == "Order")
                {
                $("#OrderReceivedYesNo").show();
            }

        });
    });

Comment: now i edited my question

Comment: What edit? And what was the result of adding the `console.log()` statement?

Comment: Change `this.value` to `$(this).val()`

Comment: stephen  $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#POVisitID").change(function () {
            
            console.log('xxx');
            if (this.value == "Order")
            {
               
                $("#OrderReceivedYesNo").show();
            }

        });
    });
 but its not working  :(

Comment: No shaun i tried that also but no use . its not working.. :(

Comment: @Sruthi, I have rolled back you changes. You cannot change the original code (making all the previous comments and any answers meaningless. If you want to show new code you have tried, append it to the bottom of your original code. - And the code have shown works fine - I will create a fiddle for you shortly.

Comment: Refer [this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/0ktmp4nh/)

Comment: yes in fiddle its working but in my application its not working i cant able to find the mistake

Comment: Then what errors are you getting in the browser console? you need to debug your code.

Comment: wait again  i have a check

Answer (score 0):

Solution  for my question.

```
 $(document).ready(function () {
    $("#OrderReceivedYesNo").hide();

    $("#POVisitID").change(function () {

        if ($("#POVisitID option:selected").text() == "Order") {
            $("#OrderReceivedYesNo").show();
        }
        else {
            $("#OrderReceivedYesNo").hide();
        }
    });
});
```